# gcloud get region name from inside GKE workload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to get current region information from inside a workload on GKE?

It's an alpine instance, specifically `gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:357.0.0-alpine` and there is no `curl` or `wget` and there's no way to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Your GKE cluster use Compute Engine to run the workload. By the way, you can use the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/default-metadata-values#vm_instance_metadata) to get the zone information. When you have the zone, remove the 2 last characters and you have the region!

Comment: Doing curl on metadata server is not possible and using gcloud compute commands are giving permission denied

Comment: Why curl is not possible?

Comment: curl is not installed. I get the error `curl not found`. Installing requires root access which is not possible.

Comment: CURL is not mandatory! You have a lot of other solution to perform a GET to a URL. wget or python code for instance, or other piece of code that you deploy with your workload.